# "Content of the book" OR "Content in the book"?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm not sure which one is appropriate.

Here's the sentence I want to fit it in -

> Any resemblance with the content {**of** | **in**} the book is purely intentional.

Comment: Googlefight "Content of the book”  427 000 “Content in the book” 36 100 quite supports @ANNA CULLEN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe 'of' is the correct word in this context because the reference is primarily to the book itself as opposed to something that is IN the book.